# Run an Arduino language from a Java project

Tags: java, arduino

I'm building a project in Java language, and I need to run [Arduino Uno](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) from my 
project. How am I supposed to do that?

The Arduino software have, I think, the C language so do I need to plant this language in my project?

Or install the Java language into the controller?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to communicate with the Arduino from a Java program? There are lots of links discussing that. You're not going to run Java *on* an Arduino. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: To the arduino has programs that written in C language So the question is how do I put  these programs in my project that  written in java language
And enables the controller from my program

Comment: You don't really put them in your project; you run code on the Arduino that your Java program can talk to. Normally this is done via the FTDI cable or the USB port.

Answer (score 0):

Java cannot be compiled to run on an Arduino because it runs on a  Atmel AVR 8-bit RISC microcontroller. The [Arduino language](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage), while similar to C/C++, links against [AVR Libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html) and allows the use of any of its functions.

If you are just looking to use a different IDE, take a look at [this](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse) (Eclipse) or [this](http://java.dzone.com/news/arduino-development-using) (Netbeans).